# Searching in VS2010 using regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, search

I need to find all strings in solution that contains some string and they are not commented:
do not find:

```
//if (condition) { ... }
find:
if (condition) { ... }
```

Trying to use `regex` in searching box: `^[\w]{1,}\bcondition\b`
Not working.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: Also I try that regex: `^\[a-zA-z ]{1,}\bcondition\b`. Not working.

Comment: \w doesn't include whitespace and tab, so you get no result if your line start with whitespace and tab.

Comment: and "if (" also contains space, so it won't match